# How to move file into another directory which have current date and time stamp (YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM) in shell

Tags: powershell, shell, sh, winscp

I want to move one file from one folder to another. Another folder is randomly generating with date and time stamp at run time in YYYY-MM-DD_DD-MM format. The code is given below. I need to give path of current timestamp in this YYYY-MM-DD_DD-MM format.

Written Some Code for same

```
# Command to execute
execute_cmd=mv

path=/home/centos

# Files inside actual_dir has to be moved
actual_dir="$path/Input_File"

# This is the directory where files will be moved and kept
backup_dir="$path/Archive/{$Here I want to write some code so that I can move into one particular folder with date and time stamp YYYY-MM-DD_DD-MM} "
```

Comment: you can set a datstamp variable with: export Date_Dir=\`date 
+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M\`

Comment: after that it's straight forward to used mkdir to make the dir, i would suggest testing either the error code from the mkdir or using an if with the -e option to test if the directory exists before continuing with the code execution. like example: mkdir $dir ; if [ -e $dir2 ] then ; cp -R $dir1 $dir2; fi

Comment: I misread your request. that's an odd date format, however you can set a datestamp variable with: export Date_Dir=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%d-%m`

Comment: GaryB .. You mean to say I need to set variable

 Date_Dir=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`

# Files inside actual_dir has to be moved
actual_dir="$path/Input_File"
backup_dir="$path/Archeive/Date_Dir  

Something like this???

Comment: yes. build your destination dir. you're missing the $ on $Date_Dir, but yes.

Comment: also when you follow a variable by anything except whitespace, it's a good idea to wrap the variable in {} like: backup_dir="${path]/Archive/${Date_Dir}"